# Why R can't scrape these links?

Tags: r, xpath, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape links and clicks from the url listed below. I'm able to scrape "clicks" using xPath but I have issue while scraping "links": these data are "NA". Could please anyone explain this and how to fix it? Here's my script

```
library(RSelenium)
library(XML)
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr= "192.168.99.100", port = 4445L)
remDr$open()

remDr$navigate("http://bit.d o")
logbutton <- remDr$findElement("css selector", "#top_login_info a:nth-child(1)")
logbutton$clickElement()
user <- remDr$findElement('css selector', '#login_user_username')
pass <- remDr$findElement('css selector', '#login_user_password')
user$sendKeysToElement(list('test0001'))
pass$sendKeysToElement(list('qwerty1234'))
logb <- remDr$findElement('css selector', '.btn-primary')
logb$clickElement()
remDr$navigate('http://bit.d o/admin/url/http%3A%7C%7C2F%7C%7C2Fedition.cnn.com%7C%7C2F2017%7C%7C2F07%7C%7C2F21%7C%7C2Fopinions%7C%7C2Ftrump-russia-putin-lain-opinion%7C%7C2Findex.html')

html <- htmlParse(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]])
clicks = xpathSApply(html,'//td//span[(((count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1) = 1) and parent::*)]')
links = xpathSApply(html, '//td//br+//a')
```

IMPORTANT: I HAD TO PUT A SPACE BETWEEN "D" AND "O" IN DOMAIN NAME DUE TO A SO RESTRICTION

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have an incorrect XPATH for links. I used [selector gadget](http://selectorgadget.com/) and extracted the following for the links (wasn't sure which you are interested in, so xpaths for both short (bit.do/...) and long (cnn.com./...) links are below:

```
short_links <- xpathSApply(html, '//td//a[(((count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1) = 2) and parent::*)]')
long_links <- xpathSApply(html, '//span[(((count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1) = 5) and parent::*)]')
```

By the way, be careful with the credentials (login and password) you have provided in the question. I would delete them shortly after you got your answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your advice regarding the credentials questions. About this I don't care of providing them because they are testing ones. Anyway I need short links and the xpath you provided worked but I'm still confused: I'm using selector gadget too (v 1.1) but I still get the same xpath i wrote above. How is it possible that you got different result? Is my version outdated?

Comment: @MassimoPotenzi I think it is because of how you use the SelectorGadget. It is not that straitforward, I had to learn how to use it through try-and-error. To get Xpath you need, you first should click on the desired element (and all similar elements will be yellow). AFTER that you should click on the elements that you don't need (the clicked will become red and some other will stop being yellow) until the yellow boxes will be only on the elements you need.

Comment: Yes @Alexey Knorre I already knew this, I did exactely the same. You could try by yourself on the page I gave: isolating short links (http:// bit.d o/scrptest*) selector gadget finds 7 elements, just the short links. Despite of this it says Xpath should be '//td//br+//a' and css 'td br+ a'. I also tried to reinstall selector gadget but nothing changed :(

Comment: @MassimoPotenzi have no idea. Try a different browser.