# Cleaning HTML code in R: how to clean this list?

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I know that this question has been asked here tons of times but after reading a bunch of topics I'm still stucked on this :( . I've a list of scraped html nodes like this

```
<a href="http://bit.d o/bnRinN9" target="_blank" style="color: #ff7700; font-weight: bold;">http://bit.d o/bnRinN9</a>
```

and I just want to clean all code part. Unfortunately I'm a newbie and the only thing it comes to my mind is the Cthulhu way (regex, argh!). Which way I can do this?

*I put a space between "d" and "o" in domain name because SO doesn't allow to post that link

Comment: What did you tried?

Comment: I tried `cleanlinks <- gsub('<.*?>', ' ', short_links)` but this clean everything

Answer (score 1):

This uses the  data linked in [Why R can't scrape these links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45532580/why-r-cant-scrape-these-links) which was downloaded.

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)

# read the saved htm page and make one string
lines <- readLines("~/Downloads/testlink.html")
text <- paste0(lines, collapse = "\n")

# the lnks are within a table, within spans. There issnt much structure
# and no identfiers so it needs a little hacking to get the right elements
# There probably are smarter css selectors that could avoid the hacks
spans <- read_html(text) %>% xml_nodes(css = "table tbody tr td span")

# extract all the short links -- but remove the links to edit
# note these links have a trailing dash - links to the statistics 
# not the content
short_links <- spans %>% xml_nodes("a") %>% xml_attr("href")
short_links <- short_links[!str_detect(short_links, "/edit")]

# the real urls are in the html text, prefixed with http
span_text  <- spans %>% html_text() %>% unlist()
long_links <- span_text[str_detect(span_text, "http")]

# > short_links
# [1] "http://bit.dxo/scrprtest7-" "http://bit.dxo/scrprtest6-" "http://bit.dxo/scrprtest5-" "http://bit.dxo/scrprtest4-" "http://bit.dxo/scrprtest3-"
# [6] "http://bit.dxo/scrprtest2-" "http://bit.dox/scrprtest1-"
# > long_links
# [1] "http://edition.cnn.com/2017/07/21/opinions/trump-russia-putin-lain-opinion/index.html"
# [2] "http://edition.cnn.com/2017/07/21/opinions/trump-russia-putin-lain-opinion/index.html"
# [3] "http://edition.cnn.com/2017/07/21/opinions/trump-russia-putin-lain-opinion/index.html"
# [4] "http://edition.cnn.com/2017/07/21/opinions/trump-russia-putin-lain-opinion/index.html"
# [5] "http://edition.cnn.com/2017/07/21/opinions/trump-russia-putin-lain-opinion/index.html"
# [6] "http://edition.cnn.com/2017/07/21/opinions/trump-russia-putin-lain-opinion/index.html"
# [7] "http://edition.cnn.com/2017/07/21/opinions/trump-russia-putin-lain-opinion/index.html"
```

Answer (score 0):

library rvest includes many simple functions for scraping and processing  html. It depends on package xml2. Generally you can scrape and filter in one step.

It's not clear if you want to extract the href value or the html text, which are the same in your example. This code extracts the href value by finding the `a` nodes and then the html attribute `href`. alternatively you can use `html_text` to get the link display text.

```
library(rvest)
links <- list('
<a href="http://anydomain.com/bnRinN9" target="_blank" style="color: #ff7700; font-weight: bold;">http://anydomain.com/bnRinN9</a>
<a href="domain.com/page">
')

# make one string
text <- paste0(links, collapse = "\n")
hrefs <- read_html(text) %>% xml_nodes("a") %>% xml_attr("href")
hrefs  


## [1] "http://anydomain.com/bnRinN9" "domain.com/page"
```

Comment: Hi, @epi99 thank you for your answer. Since href attribute and text are the same in this case they are equivalent to me but let's say I need to scrape just text. Unfortunately I can't use the method you posted because all my nodes are in a list object so I need a different one. Also I don't understand why the regex example I posted doesn't work

Comment: @massimo, 1) if all your links are in a list object, using something like `paste(list_of_links, collapse = "\n")` should give you a single string with all the links.  2) a regex like `gsub("<[^>]+>", "", short_links)` should work. I think the `.*` in your regex consumes it all but I am not sure. This `[^>]` matches everything upto (but not including `>`), then matches the `>`, and then repeats. 3) providing test data as reproducible (in this case as a list) will get you faster answers

Comment: unfortunately the solutions you provided didn't work. Using paste function I get a strange series of `[1] "<pointer: 0x00000000119e3f00>\n<pointer: 0x00000000119e5110>\n<pointer: 0x00000000119e7520>\n<pointer: 0x00000000119ea830>\n<pointer: 0x00000000119eaab0>` and with regex I get a blank list of `" "`. If you want to give a try with my code and data you could look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45532580/why-r-cant-scrape-these-links), thank you!