# Can't paste a list item without losing data

Tags: r, html-lists

I have a list item I got by scraping an html page by xpathSApply function. The object is a list of nodes like this:

```
[[1]]
<a href="http://example.org/bnRinN1" target="_blank" style="color: #ff7700; font-weight: bold;">http://example.org/bnRinN1</a> 
[[2]]
<a href="http://example.org/bnRinN2" target="_blank" style="color: #ff7700; font-weight: bold;">http://example.org/bnRinN2</a>
```

and so on. If I try to paste it in a text file or to apply a gsub function I get a list of

```
"<pointer: 0x00000000119e4a00>" 
"<pointer: 0x00000000119e6190>" 
"<pointer: 0x00000000119e9db0>"
"<pointer: 0x00000000119b3ee0>"
```

What's wrong with that?

Comment: Can you add your code, please?
It is not clear what you're trying to achive (do you want the entire `<a>` element or the link only?)...

Comment: What is trying to do is written here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45564669/cleaning-html-code-in-r-how-to-clean-this-list, but when I try to lauch gsub or paste I get the result written above