# Why I can't paste this list?

Tags: r, list

I'm trying to clean scraped html nodes. I already got a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45564669/cleaning-html-code-in-r-how-to-clean-this-list/45603667#45603667) but what I simply can't understand is why paste or gsub function doesn't work properly with lists "clicks" and "links".

```
library(RSelenium)
library(XML)
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr= "192.168.99.100", port = 4445L,  browserName='chrome')
remDr$open()

# login to access to protected data
remDr$navigate("http://bit.d o")
logbutton <- remDr$findElement("css selector", "#top_login_info a:nth-child(1)")
logbutton$clickElement()
user <- remDr$findElement('css selector', '#login_user_username')
pass <- remDr$findElement('css selector', '#login_user_password')
user$sendKeysToElement(list('test0001'))
pass$sendKeysToElement(list('qwerty1234'))
logb <- remDr$findElement('css selector', '.btn-primary')
logb$clickElement()
Sys.sleep(3)    
remDr$navigate('http://bit.d o/admin/url/http%3A%7C%7C2F%7C%7C2Fedition.cnn.com%7C%7C2F2017%7C%7C2F07%7C%7C2F21%7C%7C2Fopinions%7C%7C2Ftrump-russia-putin-lain-opinion%7C%7C2Findex.html')

# getting data
html <- htmlParse(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]])
clicks = xpathSApply(html,'//td//span[(((count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1) = 1) and parent::*)]')
links = xpathSApply(html, '//td//a[(((count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1) = 2) and parent::*)]')

text_links <- paste0(links)
text_links 

# Opening text_links the result is a strange list of 

[1] "<pointer: 0x000000001bf11b30>" "<pointer: 0x000000001bf125b0>"
[3] "<pointer: 0x000000001bf132b0>" "<pointer: 0x000000001bf15fb0>"
[5] "<pointer: 0x000000001bf17bb0>" "<pointer: 0x000000001bf1abb0>"
[7] "<pointer: 0x000000001bf1c230>"
```

As you can see the result is not what one would expected to see. The same happens with a simply gsub function. Why?

Comment: Could you share `str(clicks)`?

Comment: `xpathApply` provide nodes, with `paste0` you're coercing to characters something that is not a string. see `class(links[1])`

Comment: @ChiPak `$ :Classes 'XMLInternalElementNode', 'XMLInternalNode', 'XMLAbstractNode' <externalptr>` this is the result for all 7 elements. @Moody_Mudskipper class function says links is a list, how can I solve this?